# How to change url with a scroll in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I catch the scroll and bring it to the console, how can I change the location when scrolling up and down? I can not display the console current `location.path`. Help me to understand. I understand that I need a `forEach` to change the path

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        menuOpen: false,
        urlSite: ['/', '/about', '/products', '/partners', '/portfolio', '/contact']
    };
}

componentWillMount = () => {
    window.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
        this.scrollSite(e.wheelDelta);
    })
};

scrollSite(y){
    if(y < 0){
        console.log('slide up')
    } else {
        console.log('slide down')
    }
}

<div className="content">
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    <Route path="/products" component={Products} />
    <Route path="/partners" component={Partners} />
    <Route path="/portfolio" component={Portfolio} />
    <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a partial example. I haven't figured out how to also scroll to the component when the url is type, but I'll edit the answer once I get that working.

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
// Create Refs - marking the DOM elements for the scroll
this.contactComponent = React.createRef();
}
componentDidMount() {
 window.addEventListener("scroll", this.onScroll);
}
componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.onScroll);
}
onScroll = e => {
  let scrollingStoped;
  if (!scrollingStoped) {
   window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
     // Find and store the DOM nodes
     const contactComponent = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(
       this.contactComponent.current

  );
     // Define the bounds holder variables
     let contactTop = null;

     // Get the bounds of each compoenent and store it in the above defined holders
     if (contactComponent) {
       contactTop = contactComponent.getBoundingClientRect().top;
     }
     // Push the url updates if the component in view is within the boundary + 20 border
     if (contactTop !== null && contactTop < 20) {
      this.props.history.push(`/contact`);
     } else {
      // Checks the current page and updates the base url using it
      if (this.props.currentPage === "home") {
        this.props.history.push(`/`);
      } else {
        this.props.history.push(`/${this.props.currentPage}`);
      }
     }
     scrollingStoped = false;
    });

    scrollingStoped = true;
  }
};
```